# Calling a method in another class from a button in (MainActivity.java)

Tags: android

My code should write a file once the button is clicked from the MainActivity.
I've drawn a blank why I get the message "Unfortunately My Application has stopped" when clicking the button when running on the emulator.(Android Studio 2.2.3)
Thanks for any insight.

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button;
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Class2 Class2_ref = new Class2();
                    Class2_ref.method();

                }
            });
        }
    }


//Class2
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Class2 extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = Class2.class.getName();
    private static final String FILENAME = "myFile.txt";

    public void method(){
        String textToSaveString = "Hello World";
        writeToFile(FILENAME, textToSaveString);
    }

    public void writeToFile(String filename, String data) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in the Android Monitor? (Error message)

Comment: why are you extending Activity for your Class2

Comment: The error is: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I have never seen a path for outputStreamWriter in any example. I want to write data for just this app on internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `openFileOutput` method, you have to provide full path for `outputStreamWriter`, please write your error trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class2{

    private static final String TAG = Class2.class.getName();
    private static final String FILENAME = "myFile.txt";
    public void method(){
        String textToSaveString = "Hello World";
        writeToFile(FILENAME, textToSaveString);
    }

    public void writeToFile(String filename, String data) {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename);
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bw.write("CONTENT HERE");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (bw != null)
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Try this one Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately the code crashes too. I'm I calling the method from the main Activity wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong this code.. Its current running in one of my projects

Comment: The error is:
Unfortunately my application has stopped

Process: com.example.name.myapplication, PID: 2558
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: told you to try the above code.. There is no such line like openFileOutput() in the above code

Comment: Using the MainActivity  from my original post and the code for "Class2" it crashes on button press.

Comment: need to write to Internal storage. Sorry for the confusion.

W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
W/System.err:     at com.example.name.myapplication.Class2.writeToFile(Class2.java:26)
W/System.err:     at com.example.name.myapplication.Class2.method(Class2.java:16)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    give the above in your manifest

Comment: Thanks Mr. Popular,
Adding to the manifest resolved my issue.